# How to parse Google Custom Search API response in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I have this code:

```
public void googleSearch() throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" + key + "&cx=" + cx + "&q=" + qry + "&alt=json&queriefields=queries(request(totalResults))");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Object obj = mapper.readValue(output, Object.class);
        System.out.println(obj);

    }

    conn.disconnect();
}
```

Where I am trying to parse the JSON response from google using Jackson 2, to manage the data returned. I only need image links and descriptions, however, I am unable to get parsed data at all. I get this error when I run this code:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: {; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: {; line: 1, column: 3]
```

How do I separate the image links and information I need and make it more manageable? (I'm assuming by parsing the JSON into a java object and then being able to call the object variables, but just not sure how exactly)

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the response line-by-line, and send **each line individually** to Jackson. so if the response is something like this

```
{
  "property1": "value1"
  ...
}
```

Jackson gets an input json string `"{"` and of course this is invalid.

You should send the whole `conn.getInputStream()` to Jackson (and sure enough, `ObjectMapper` has such an api)

and while we are at it, parsong into an `Object` is not a good idea, since the whole point of Jackson data bind api is to bind the json into a **concrete** (usually user made) Java class.  If you really want to parse into a general-purpose container, send a `Map` into Jackson:

```
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(conn.getInputStream(), Map.class);
```

...then `System.out.println` will also work properly.

another option is call `readTree()` and use the `JsonNode` general-purpose data structure.

and while we are at it, instead of parsing long json structures, have you looked into [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) ?

Comment: How would I retreive the values from the JSON? I've read about using a key, but I don't know what the keys are in the Google response. I tried         System.out.println(map.get("src"));
But it just prints null.

Comment: Print the map. it will tell you what keys and values it contains